# Calling a method in a class, objects conflict?

Tags: matlab, oop, events

I have two classes:

```
classdef ToggleButton < handle
   properties
      State = false
   end
   events
      ToggledState
   end
   methods
      function OnStateChange(obj,newState)
         if newState ~= obj.State
            obj.State = newState;
            notify(obj,'ToggledState');
         end
      end
   end
end
```

and

```
classdef RespondToToggle < handle
   methods
      function obj = RespondToToggle(toggle_button_obj)
         addlistener(toggle_button_obj,'ToggledState',@obj.handleEvnt);
      end
      function handleEvnt(~,src,~)
         if src.State
            disp('ToggledState is true')
            obj.hello
         end
      end
      function hello(obj)
          disp('that works')
      end
   end
end
```

So I would like to be able to call the function "hello" from the function handleEvnt, as both belong to the same class, RespondToToggle.

Here is the error I get:

```
>> button=ToggleButton;
>> responder=RespondToToggle(button);
>> OnStateChange(button,1)
ToggledState is true
Warning: Error occurred while executing callback:
Undefined variable "obj" or class "obj.hello".

Error in RespondToToggle/handleEvnt (line 9)
            obj.hello

Error in RespondToToggle>@(varargin)obj.handleEvnt(varargin{:}) (line 4)
         addlistener(toggle_button_obj,'ToggledState',@obj.handleEvnt);

Error in ToggleButton/OnStateChange (line 12)
            notify(obj,'ToggledState');

> In ToggleButton>ToggleButton.OnStateChange at 12
```

Can you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: `function handleEvnt(~,src,~)`, where is your obj reference? Should be `function handleEvnt(obj,~,src,~)` or `function handleEvnt(obj,src,~)`

Comment: @Michaël It may be worth sitting down and reading through the documentation on classes a little bit to understand some of the [basics of MATLAB classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html).